# Count of duplicate selection in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a count for every option in select option, below is the function I made to do so but I realized all it does it count how many users haven't made a selection. I want it to count how many times each option has been selected in database instead, anyone have any advice?

```
function teamCount($mysqli){
$count = "SELECT count(selection) FROM users GROUP BY selection HAVING count(*) > 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($count);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo '('.$rows[0].')';
}
```

below is table mock up:

```
 username     selection
 .....         Buffalo bills
 .....         Baltimore ravens
```

I would like the count to go through the selection column and count duplicate entries in database so it appears as such on front end:

```
Buffalo Bills [1]
Baltimore Ravens [1]
```

Comment: Please describe relevant database tables.

Comment: Please don't mix OOP with procedural style.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = "SELECT selection, count(*) FROM users GROUP BY selection HAVING count(*) > 1";
```

you can try this one.